# Other placement of fields everytime i run the code

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I'm stuck with my application. Every time I run my code, my fields e.g. `fromTextField` once have width 180 other time my width `private static final Integer widthField = 232`.

---

Code:

---

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MailGui extends JFrame {
    private static final Integer widthField = 232;

private MailGui() {
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

        JLabel fromLabel = new JLabel("From: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JLabel passwdLabel = new JLabel("Password: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JLabel toLabel = new JLabel("To: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JLabel subjectLabel = new JLabel("Subject: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Content: ", SwingConstants.LEFT);

        JTextField fromTextField = new JTextField();

        JTextField toTextField = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField passwdPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
        JTextField subjectTextField = new JTextField();
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(8, 30);

        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);

        northPanel.add(fromLabel);
        northPanel.add(fromTextField);

        northPanel.add(passwdLabel);
        northPanel.add(passwdPasswordField);

        northPanel.add(toLabel);
        northPanel.add(toTextField);

        northPanel.add(subjectLabel);
        northPanel.add(subjectTextField);

        northPanel.add(textLabel);
        northPanel.add(textArea);

        this.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(sendButton);

        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.pack();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);


        fromTextField.setBounds(textArea.getX() + 100, 0, widthField, 19);
        passwdPasswordField.setBounds(textArea.getX() + 100, 19, widthField, 19);
        toTextField.setBounds(textArea.getX() + 100, 38, widthField, 19);
        subjectTextField.setBounds(textArea.getX() + 100, 57, widthField,         19);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MailGui();
    }
}
```

---

What I have:

---

[image: First]

---

Or

---

[image: Second]

---

What I except:

---

[image: Second]

---

Thanks for every help. Q.

Comment: That code has some suspicious and less than optimal code in it, but I ran it 6 times and got the [same result **every** time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InMYN.png).

Comment: That's wired... Then what should I do with that? Any suggestions?

Comment: To begin with: 1) Start the GUI on the EDT. 2) Don't try to set an explicit size or position or location for components. Instead use layouts and layout padding for the required effect. 3) Don't use a `GridLayout` for the label & field combos. The grid layout will make all components the same width. Instead maybe use a `GridBagLayout` for that section. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the setBounds() method does nothing. The layout manager will override the size/location based on the rules of the layout manager. In the case of the GridLayout all components will be sized to the preferred size of the largest component or as the frame size is changes each cell will adjust to fill the space available in the frame.

When you create a JTextField the code should be something like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
```

This will allow the text field to determine its own preferred size to display 15 "W" characters based on the font of the text field.

Then the layout manager can do a better job at determining the size of each component

If you want the widths of the labels and the text fields to be different, then you need to use a different layout manager. Probably a GridBagLayout. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Note the tutorial examples show you how to create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Answer (score 0):

Call `pack()` at the end of the GUI composition in order to layout it in a definite way once.

The dependency of the geometry to textArea is unfortunate. Put it in the layout too.

There are nice GUI editors with more complex layout managers.